# How to add Plugin Dependencies in VSCode with "Extension Pack for Java"?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to setup VSCode to work on Java projects, but I'm running into some issues.

I currently use Eclipse (the "ide for rcp and rap developers" version/package).

In many of my projects, I have runtime dependencies and during development I specify a "Plug-In Dependencies" folder that points to the directory where these runtime jar files are.

This allows my code to compile and also my project does not have to contain all those referenced jar files when I export and create a jar because they will be available at runtime.

I have setup VSCode with the Extension Pack for Java, but it doesn't seem to recognize the plugin dependencies and all those imports are unable to be resolved.

Is there a way I can add these dependencies?

Comment: Open Command Palette and click **Maven: Add a dependency**, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you intended to set a target platform to the project?

Comment: I cannot/don't use maven for my projects, our dependencies are in a local folder during development, and at runtime they will be available by the runtime/JVM.

Target platform, where do I set that for VSCode?

I feel like i need to be configuring VSCode with settings to tell it which Java SDK/version to use, etc. But can't figure out where/how

Comment: Not sure if the target platform is the same thing as the plugin dependencies you mentioned. The target platform is something defined like this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/blob/main/java-extension/com.microsoft.java.test.plugin/target.target. If this is exactly what you want. You can try this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yaozheng.vscode-pde.